# How do I reinstall bootloader?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I was running Win 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 alongside each other on diffirent partitions. I recently upgraded to Win 8 and after installing it, it booted directly on Win 8.

I've put in my pendrive to run Ubuntu from it, and I can see that my Ubuntu installation is still installed on the harddrive.

How do I get the bootloader to work again without reinstalling Ubuntu again?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Windows on your computer automatically installs Microsoft;s bootloader, which is incompatible with Ubuntu. What you need to do is to create a Boot Repair USB and boot from it, which will reinstall Ubuntu's bootloader. Detailed instructions for doing this can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out/), follow these steps:

- Boot the liveCD
- Open a Terminal and type in the following commands, noting that the first command will put you into the grub “prompt”, and the next 3 commands will be executed there. Also note that hd0,0 implies the first hard drive and the first partition on that drive, which is where you probably installed grub to during installation. If not, then adjust accordingly:

  ```
  sudo grub
  root (hd0,0)
  setup (hd0)
  exit
  ```
- Reboot (removing the liveCD), and your boot menu should be back.