# Missing Operating System after removing Windows though partition (gparted)

Tags: installation, boot, partitioning, system

My laptop is divided into three drives: C, D and E. Windows was installed in C and Ubuntu was in D. I format C and E by deleting and to NTFS using gparted. But when I restart, it tells me a "missing Operating System". How can I tell the BIOS to boot from D? Or is there anything I can do? I installed several big software in the Ubuntu system, so I don't want to reboot from a USB and to lose the saved data. 
Thanks!

Thanks for all your answers. My question is solved. I just reboot from a USB and re-install the system and software.

Comment: It sounds like you were using WUBI, in which case, you're going to have to reinstall the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Try Boot-Repair.

> Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may
>   encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing
>   Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows
>   after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some
>   upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

To use boot repair, you can download the [ISO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/), and brun it to a CD.  Once the CD is done, go ahead and boot from it, and just follow the directions.

<sup>Source:[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your bootloader was installed on C: and in formatting that, you lost your bootloader.

See here:
[How do I reinstall bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211090/how-do-i-reinstall-bootloader)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to repair GRUB. The easiest way to do that is probably to use Boot Repair application. Just do these on Live-CD or Live-USB session. You do not need to burn on CD anything if You have disc or pen-drive with any version of Ubuntu or - I think - even any Debian distribution installer.
Anyway launch Terminal and paste following commands there to install Grub Repair.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

After installation, launch Boot Repair using Bash and try default repair. Reboot. If the problem still occurs You can try Boot Repair advanced options.